# how does scipy single euclidian linkage work

Tags: python, scipy

I have symmetric dataframe of distances with zeros as main diagonal. I'm trying to understand how does `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(np.triu(D))` work, where D is that dataframe of distances.

I tried this function:

```
def make_cluster(distances):
    res, clusters = [], []
    for i in range(distances.shape[0]):
        for j in range(distances.shape[0]):
            if i >= j: continue
            res.append(((distances.iloc[i, :] - distances.iloc[j, :]) ** 2).sum() ** (0.5))
            clusters.append((i, j))

    res = pd.Series(res, index=clusters)

    cluster_idx = res.index[res.argmin()]
    cluster_value = res[cluster_idx]
    cluster_labels = distances.index[cluster_idx[0]], distances.index[cluster_idx[1]]

    return cluster_idx, cluster_value, cluster_labels
```

And the first cluster is the same as scipy provides me. Okay, seems good, thought I...
I read that I need to update distances, so I did that code:

```
def update_distances(distances_orig, distances, cluster_labels, cluster_label):
    '''Last row and column is a new cluster'''
    for label in distances_orig.index:
        if label in cluster_labels: continue
        # distances.loc[cluster_label, label] = np.min([distances_orig.loc[cluster_labels[0], label], distances_orig.loc[cluster_labels[1], label]])
        distances.loc[cluster_label, label] = np.max([distances_orig.loc[cluster_labels[0], label], distances_orig.loc[cluster_labels[1], label]])

distances.iloc[:, -1] = distances.iloc[-1, :]

return distances
```

So it looks something like this:

```
cluster_idx, cluster_value, cluster_labels = make_cluster(pd.DataFrame(np.triu(D), index=D.index, columns=D.columns))
D = D.loc[~D.index.isin(cluster_labels), ~D.columns.isin(cluster_labels)] #? exclude
cluster_label = ", ".join(cluster_labels)
D.loc[cluster_label, cluster_label] = 0
D = update_distances(D_orig, D, cluster_idx, cluster_labels, cluster_label)
```

So I thought I can just do another "iteration" and just simply use `make_cluster` again, but ... I have different result. For example, scipy says second cluster with value 0.72234004 and my function says its 0.7257478298550506 though cluster labels the same, I think it's just coincedence.

Can someone answer me what am I doing wrong? I tried to look in source code but the final wall was "interface" or some weired things with typing in `_hierarchy.pyi`. Sorry, I cant provide the exact same data: a lot of data. Let's just go with this example:

```
distances = pd.DataFrame(data=[
[0, 17, 23, 15],
[17, 0, 31, 12],
[23, 31, 0, 25],
[15, 12, 25, 0],
], columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"], index=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
distances_orig = distances.copy()
link = sch.linkage(np.triu(distances))
print(link)
cluster_idx, cluster_value, cluster_labels = make_cluster(pd.DataFrame(np.triu(distances), index=distances.index, columns=distances.columns))
print(cluster_idx, cluster_value, cluster_labels)
distances = distances.loc[~distances.index.isin(cluster_labels), ~distances.columns.isin(cluster_labels)] #? exclude
cluster_label = ", ".join(cluster_labels)
distances.loc[cluster_label, cluster_label] = 0
distances = update_distances(distances_orig, distances, cluster_idx, cluster_labels, cluster_label)
print(distances)
cluster_idx, cluster_value, cluster_labels = make_cluster(pd.DataFrame(np.triu(distances), index=distances.index, columns=distances.columns))
print(cluster_idx, cluster_value, cluster_labels)
```

I tried both min and max as you can see in my `update_distances` function.

UPD
updated my functions

```py
def calc_euclid_distance(ser_1, ser_2):
    return ((ser_1 - ser_2) ** 2).sum() ** 0.5

def update_distances(distances_orig, distances, cluster_labels, cluster_label):
    '''Last row and column is a new cluster'''
    for label in distances_orig.index:
        if label in cluster_labels: continue

        distances.loc[label, cluster_label] = np.min([
            calc_euclid_distance(distances_orig.loc[cluster_labels[0], :], distances_orig.loc[label, :]),
            calc_euclid_distance(distances_orig.loc[cluster_labels[1], :], distances_orig.loc[label, :]),
        ])

    return distances

def make_cluster(distances):
    res, clusters = [], []
    for i in range(distances.shape[0]):
        for j in range(distances.shape[0]):
            if i >= j: continue
            res.append(calc_euclid_distance(distances.iloc[i, :], distances.iloc[j, :]))
            clusters.append((i, j))

    res = pd.Series(res, index=clusters)

    cluster_idx = res.index[res.argmin()]
    cluster_value = res[cluster_idx]
    cluster_labels = distances.index[cluster_idx[0]], distances.index[cluster_idx[1]]

    return cluster_idx, cluster_value, cluster_labels
```

So, please, if you want to help - use this functions and that example:

```py
distances = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [0, 17, 23, 15],
    [17, 0, 31, 12],
    [23, 31, 0, 25],
    [15, 12, 25, 0],
], columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"], index=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
distances = pd.DataFrame(np.triu(distances), index=distances.index, columns=distances.columns)
distances_orig = distances.copy()
link = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(distances)
print(link)
cluster_idx, cluster_value, cluster_labels = make_cluster(distances)
print(cluster_idx, cluster_value, cluster_labels)
distances = distances.loc[~distances.index.isin(cluster_labels), ~distances.columns.isin(cluster_labels)] #? exclude
cluster_label = ", ".join(cluster_labels)
distances.loc[cluster_label, cluster_label] = 0
distances = update_distances(distances_orig, distances, cluster_labels, cluster_label).fillna(0)
cluster_idx, cluster_value, cluster_labels = make_cluster(distances)
print(cluster_idx, cluster_value, cluster_labels)
```

As you can see, second iteration is really close, but not exactly the same.